# Calculating a forecast's tracking signal in R

Tags: r, signals, tracking

I'd like to ask if there is any R package with a function for calculating and plotting the tracking signal of a time series forecast, supposing that I have a list of real and predicted values.

I've searched a lot and haven't found anything for R, and I think it would be quite cumbersome and very inefficient to calculate it with loops.

Comment: You do not need loops, all necessary operations can be vectorized ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy to compute it manually, without loops :) Suppose your forecast is contained into vector `z` and your data are stored in `y`:

```
trackingSignal = ifelse(cumsum(abs(z-y))==0, 0, 1:length(z)*cumsum(z - y)/cumsum(abs(z-y)))
```

Comment: Thanks! although I think there's probably something wrong in the formula, as it gives me a single number but I'll try to see how to get it

Comment: The tracking signal is a single number according to this definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_signal

Comment: You seems not happy with the answer: may I know what definition of tracking signal you have in mind?

Comment: That same definition, but calculated for every observation/period/row - that is, for period 1 it's calculated with the first values in the time series, for period 10 with the 10 first values (that is, the sum of the values from the first to the tenth period, excluding the ones that come next) and so on.

Comment: I edited the answer with cumsum. You need to check the denominator is not equal to 0 (hence the ifelse condition)